# Always receive org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: The target server failed to respond Android

Tags: android, email, http-post

I am working on HTTP post in android. Here is my code:

```
 SendMail sending = (SendMail) new SendMail()
                                .execute(url + "/mob/android/dummy.php");


    public class SendMail extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    private String endResult;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... val) {
        String url = val[0];
        Log.i("Url", url + "");

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

        try {

            CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
            ((AbstractHttpClient) httpclient).setCookieStore(cookieStore);

            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", post_name));
            nameValuePairs


            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", post_email));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("message",
                    "Requesting appointment from: " + SelectedDr
                            + "  Message: " + post_message));

            Log.i("nameValuePairs:", "" + nameValuePairs);

            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            BasicResponseHandler myHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            endResult = myHandler.handleResponse(response);
            Log.i("nameValuePairs", "" + nameValuePairs);
            Log.i("endResult", "" + endResult);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

        } catch (IOException e) {

        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        super.onPostExecute(result);
        publishProgress(endResult);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {

        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        String result = values[0];

        T_warning.setText("Mail Sent.");
        ET_email.setText("");
        ET_name.setText("");

        ET_message.setText("");





    }

}
```

Now till

```
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("message",
                "Requesting appointment from: " + SelectedDr
                        + "  Message: " + post_message));
```

it is working fine but on HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost); it gives no reponse after 3 minutes it gives mail sent but on my mail server I received no mail and also show exception:

> org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: The target server failed to respond

I am stuck with that I could not understand why this is happening I added all permissions

LOGCAT:

```
04-05 10:41:57.110: I/exception(3926): org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: The target server failed to respond

04-05 10:41:57.110: I/endResult(3926): null
```

**Edited Code gives LOGCAT:**

```
04-05 10:51:17.160: W/System.err(4016): org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: The target server failed to respond

04-05 10:51:17.170: W/System.err(4016):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultResponseParser.java:85)

04-05 10:51:17.170: W/System.err(4016):     at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:174)

04-05 10:51:17.170: W/System.err(4016):     at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:180)

04-05 10:51:17.170: W/System.err(4016):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:235)

04-05 10:51:17.170: W/System.err(4016):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractClientConnAdapter.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractClientConnAdapter.java:259)

04-05 10:51:17.170: W/System.err(4016):     at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:279)

04-05 10:51:17.170: W/System.err(4016):     at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:121)

04-05 10:51:17.170: W/System.err(4016):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:428)

04-05 10:51:17.170: W/System.err(4016):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)

04-05 10:51:17.170: W/System.err(4016):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:653)

04-05 10:51:17.170: W/System.err(4016):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:627)

04-05 10:51:17.170: W/System.err(4016):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:616)

04-05 10:51:17.170: W/System.err(4016):     at com.ilmasoft.alina_dental.MailUs$SendMail.doInBackground(MailUs.java:492)

04-05 10:51:17.180: W/System.err(4016):     at com.ilmasoft.alina_dental.MailUs$SendMail.doInBackground(MailUs.java:1)

04-05 10:51:17.180: W/System.err(4016):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:252)

04-05 10:51:17.180: W/System.err(4016):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)

04-05 10:51:17.180: W/System.err(4016):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)

04-05 10:51:17.180: W/System.err(4016):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1081)

04-05 10:51:17.180: W/System.err(4016):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:574)

04-05 10:51:17.180: W/System.err(4016):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1020)
```

Comment: post logcat results with question  when app is crashing to get more help from us

Comment: im asking about whole log not for two lines from it. or if you are not able to share whole log then just share `Log.i("Url", url + "");` line from logcat

Comment: URL: www.dummy.com/mob/android/dummy.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code within doInBackground

```
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", post_name));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", post_email));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("message",
                    "Requesting appointment from: " + SelectedDr
                            + "  Message: " + post_message));

        DefaultHttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient();
            ResponseHandler<String> res = new BasicResponseHandler();
            HttpPost postMethod = new HttpPost(url);
            String response = null;

            try {
                postMethod.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                response = hc.execute(postMethod, res);
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: I tried you code and it giving exceptions . Please see my edited Question

Comment: are you sure you have internet permission added in your manifest?
if yes re check url you are executing

Comment: i cannot share the actuall url but this sor of url is i am executing : http://www.dummy.com/mob/android/dummy.php

Comment: I have checked the same code in samsung duos and its working but when i run it on 10.1 tab it gives me system error

Comment: take a look at this [link](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=13117#c14)

Comment: i tried your code and its working but when i enter email other than gmail account

Comment: i believe these issues are un-related to the code. if you find something about it, please update me as well.. glad to help out aniway!

Comment: thankyou very much problem was mail server side but you help was great